# Start different activity on application restart

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application which has two activities `A` and `B`. When application is installed and run for the first time then it always starts with `A` as it is declared as launcher activity in manifest.

According to workflow, after a few seconds, activity `A` is destroyed and activity `B` is started. So that, the root of task becomes `B`. Now, when user presses the home button and later comes to our app, activity `B` is resumed as expected. But, if application is left in background for a long time then the application is restarted as from the logs `Application::onCreate()` is called. However, I want that whenever the application restarts that is whenever `Application::onCreate()` is called (like in the second case) activity `A` should be started instead of B, in all other cases when application is not restarted activity `B` should be appearing. I am new to android and unable to figure out a solution. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

In the end of your activity A you should create a preference that save the a state of your app in the SharedPreference.

at the start of onCreate() of your activities check the state and start the correct activity.